# Load testing using Jmeter with 35 users

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I am performing load test on 7 apis starting with 5 sessions(users) with target request/min to be close to 35-38(5*7) and it should increment by 2 sessions(users) after each minute (5,7,9,11..35) until it reaches 35 sessions(users) with target request/min to be close to 245. How can i achieve this?

I am trying it with the normal thread group by manually updating the users from 5…7…9 and rampup as 60..120..180...

But it doesn’t seems to a good approach

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you did get this 5*7 formula for calculating requests per minute, hopefully it's correct and you really want each user to execute 1 requests each minute.

The suitable built-in JMeter component is [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group), you can achieve the desired concurrency using the following expression:

```
rate(35/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(35/min)
rate(49/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(49/min)
rate(63/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(63/min)
rate(77/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(77/min)
rate(91/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(91/min)
rate(105/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(105/min)
rate(119/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(119/min)
rate(133/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(133/min)
rate(147/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(147/min)
rate(161/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(161/min)
rate(175/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(175/min)
rate(189/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(189/min)
rate(203/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(203/min)
rate(217/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(217/min)
rate(231/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(231/min)
rate(245/min) random_arrivals(1 min) rate(245/min)
```

[image]

However this way you won't have control over generated number of users. [See Rethinking Load Configuration With JMeter’s Open Model Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-model-thread-group) article for more details if needed.

Alternative option is using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination, these are plugins which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: 5*7 is like… 5 users are doing a page load so 7 apis are kind of hitting on that page. So based on that it is incrementally increasing the load by 2 user loading that page. If that makes sense?